# How does the let function guarantee the value won't be null?

Tags: kotlin

The `let` function guarantees the value inside the block won't be null, even if another thread changes the original value by the time the block is run... Sounds good, but how does it do that?

```
var user: User?

user?.let { it ->
  // `user` can be null at this point, but not `it`.
}
```

How does the compiler prevent the underlying object from being deallocated while this block is running? Strong reference? Critical section? Something else?

Comment: `it` is just a new reference to whatever value `user` had that was not null, so basically `if (user != null) it = user`

Answer (score 5):

It is equivalent to copying the value to a local variable and then using that. Your code is equivalent to:

```
val it = user
if (it != null) {
  // `user` can be null at this point, but not `it`.
}
```

except that `it` is confined to the scope of the lambda. So, yes, it creates a strong reference.

By the way, it only guarantees `it` is not null if using the null-safe call `?.`. If you use a standard `.let` call on a nullable, it very well could be null inside the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

## Null-Safe Operator `?.`

This behavior actually has little to do with the `let` function and has more to do with the `?.`, also known as a [null-safe operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

If you have a nullable reference `user` as in your example, a statement such as the following which includes the null-safe operator `?.`:

```kotlin
val n = user?.name
```

says: if `user` is not null, use it for the next part of the call chain (in this case referencing the `name` property) and assign the result of that to the val `n`, otherwise assign `null` to `n`.

## Scoping Functions

[`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let) is simply one of the Kotlin [scoping functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) -- its [definition in code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L108-L113) is simple. `let` takes its "receiver", or the value it is being called on, and passes that value as the first parameter to the function that is passed to `let` i.e. the `{ it -> ... }` lambda. That lambda parameter name is by default `it`, so the `it ->` part is actually redundant.

When the lambda block ends, that variable goes out of scope, hence it is "scoped" to that specific block i.e. it simply assures that the variable does not exist beyond that block.

## Bringing it Together

Now, combining the idea of the null-safe operator with the `let` scoping function, we have the code you wrote:

```kotlin
user?.let {
  // `user` can be null at this point, but not `it`.
}
```

The null-safe operator `?.` guarantees that if user is not `null`, then the next part of the chain is executed, which in this case is the `let` scoping function. If `user` is not null, then the not-null `user` becomes the receiver of the `let` and its value is assigned to `it`.

**The receiver of the `let` function is a copy of the non-null reference, so it is not affected by changes in the reference of the original `user` var e.g. if `user` is set to null by another thread.**

If the user is already null, then the `let` function is never even called. In other words, the `let` block is never executed because of the null-safe operator.

This code is equivalent to a copy of the user variable into a local variable, then an `if` statement checking if that copy is not null, which Kotlin handles with a [smart cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) for this situation:

```kotlin
val u = user
if (u != null) {
  // u cannot be null inside this block, due to smart cast
}
```

However, `?.let { ... }` is a bit more succint by avoiding the explicit assignment, and can read better when its return value is used to continue the call chain.

One last thing... if you refer back to the definition of `let`, you can see it allows a nullable receiver. That means it is valid to call a `let` function on a possibly null value, and when doing so, the `it` is nullable too:

```
user.let {
  // it can be null here
}
```

Comment: I don't think answers the question: What happens if `user` is set to `null` by another thread.

Comment: @mithunc You're right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) makes no such guarantee — in fact, like many extension functions, it can be called on a null value.

What prevents a null in this case is the `?.` [safe-call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).  That calls the following function only if the previous value is non-null.  So if `user` is null, it won't even *call* `let`.  That's why the compiler knows that if it gets into the `let` lambda, the receiver must have been non-null.

And yes, while the lambda is being executed, the `it` reference makes the `user` object reachable, and so not eligible for garbage collection.